# Resource Qualifiers - determine currently selected programatically?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm currently working on support for multiple screen sizes for my app, and stumbled upon this advice from google;
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/support-different-screen-sizes#kotlin

It has this code;

```
private fun computeWindowSizeClasses() {
    val metrics = WindowMetricsCalculator.getOrCreate()
        .computeCurrentWindowMetrics(this)

    val widthDp = metrics.bounds.width() /
        resources.displayMetrics.density
    val widthWindowSizeClass = when {
        widthDp < 600f -> WindowSizeClass.COMPACT
        widthDp < 840f -> WindowSizeClass.MEDIUM
        else -> WindowSizeClass.EXPANDED
    }

    val heightDp = metrics.bounds.height() /
        resources.displayMetrics.density
    val heightWindowSizeClass = when {
        heightDp < 480f -> WindowSizeClass.COMPACT
        heightDp < 900f -> WindowSizeClass.MEDIUM
        else -> WindowSizeClass.EXPANDED
    }

    // Use widthWindowSizeClass and heightWindowSizeClass
}
```

Then there are the in-project resource qualifiers, eg

```
/layout 
/layout-w600dp
/layout-w840dp
```

When Android chooses a layout based on width, does it use this exact same calculation?

```
widthDp = metrics.bounds.width() / resources.displayMetrics.density
```

Different layouts will have different elements. How do I ensure my class code is expecting the same layout that Android has chosen?

Comment: Generally, you should write your code to not care which layout has been chosen by the resources framework. Instead, just check to see whether the element is present or not (that is, whether `findViewById()` returns a null or non-null value). If the element is present, update it accordingly. If not, don't worry about it; it's just a tablet-only view that isn't displaying on your user's phone.

Comment: Your advice is sound. But is there really no way to know which layout Android has chosen? Instead of checking that, I'll "fake" it by looking using findViewById() (something I've not used much since switching to viewbinding).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I handle missing views in different layout configurations when using view binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66937070/how-do-i-handle-missing-views-in-different-layout-configurations-when-using-view)

Comment: No, it doesn't. But thanks. My question is how to know, in the class code, which layout Android has selected. I could have a unique view in each layout version and findViewById them all until I have one... but... surely there's a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a better answer;

```
getResources().getConfiguration()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to know, you can have a `values` resource for each resource qualifier you are supporting. For example,

values/whatever.xml:

```
<string name="resource_qualifier">default</string>
```

values-w600dp/whatever.xml:

```
<string name="resource_qualifier">w600dp</string>
```

And then you can `getString()` this resource value.

Comment: I've found a better answer you might be interested in; getResources().getConfiguration()